# htaccess redirect: change and delete parameter value

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

who help me?
i need to create a redirect with rule that delete and modify this variables:

`http://www.example.com/assets/thumb/index.php?src=/uploads/images/38/images/2/img_3761.jpg&w=880&h=587&zc=1`

to

`http://www.example.com/assets/thumb/index.php?src=/uploads/images/38/images/2/img_3761.jpg&w=1200&h=900`

i try:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^assets/thumb/index.php?src=$1&w=$2&h=$3&zc=$4
RewriteRule ^/?(assets/thumb/index.php)?$ assets/thumb/index.php?src=$1&w=$2&h=$3`

i am not expert with server rule. 
thank you

Al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^src=(.+)&w=(\d+)&h=(\d+)&zc=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^assets/thumb/index\.php$ /assets/thumb/index.php?src=%1&w=1200&h=900 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps you!